# How to generate SharedKey for Azure File Service REST API

Tags: rest, azure

I'm trying to access files in Azure File Service via REST API. According to MSDN, my request should contain a header like:

```
x-ms-version: 2015-02-21
x-ms-date: <date>
Authorization: SharedKey myaccount:CY1OP3O3jGFpYFbTCBimLn0Xov0vt0khH/D5Gy0fXvg=
```

I do see a primary and secondary access key in my Azure portal, but how can I construct the SharedKey string out of those information? I found some other posts explaining about SAS, but I don't think I can use Azure SDK in my client to construct such, and thinking of creating the HTTP request manually. Is this possible?

Comment: Please see Azure Storage REST API documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly overlooked the detail of this issue in my question. I found this link that explains the steps:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179428.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

This is quite conceptual level explanation, and found it quite daunting to actually follow it and code it from the scratch.

Looks like following link has the closest thing that I can use - which is written with JavaScript:
http://blog.programtheeworld.com/2013/03/21/putting-a-blob-in-azure-from-windows-store-app-in-javascript/

Haven't tried it yet, but that seems the best approach when my client can't use Azure SDK to construct the SharedKey.

Comment: You may find this blog post useful for understanding how to consume Azure Storage REST API - http://justazure.com/azure-blob-storage-part-5-blob-storage-rest/.